# how to drop submenu one by one?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

in the Navbar the submenu's class name is submenu , we have 7 submenus ' im trying to make something like mouse hover **but without using mouse event** , i want to show them one by one (show the first and hide it, show the second and hide it) , what is the better way to do that with **JavaScript**

here is the my code but it show them once one on the other :

```
function changestyle(){
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
        for(var i = 0; i < els.length-1; i++)
        {
           
          els[i].style.display = 'block';
        
        
        }
        }
```

i tried another code but it doesn't work :

```
function changestyle(){
            var els = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
            for(var i = 0; i < els.length-1; i++)
            {

                
                const showone = function(){
                    els[i].style.display = 'block';
                    
                  };
            
                  const hideone = function(){
                    els[i].style.display = 'none';
                    
                  };
                  setTimeout(showone, 2000);
                setTimeout(hideone, 2000);
            }
            }
```

this is the SubMenu HTML CODE :

```
<div class="submenu">
  <ul class="linkmenu">
    <li class="d-md-none">
      <div class="nav-item standalone-nav"><span><a href="/wines/_/N-n" data-nav-label="Browse all Offers"><strong>Browse all Offers</strong></a></span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="nav-item"> <span>Type</span> <i class="arrow down"></i>
      </div>
      . . . . .
      </a>
    </li> -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give also little of your html, so we can hel you

Comment: What do you mean by "but without using mouse event"?

Comment: like onclick/hover...

Comment: <div class="submenu">
  <ul class="linkmenu">
    <li class="d-md-none">
      <div class="nav-item standalone-nav"><span><a href="/wines/_/N-n" data-nav-label="Browse all Offers"><strong>Browse all Offers</strong></a></span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="nav-item"> <span>Type</span> <i class="arrow down"></i>
      </div>
      . . . . .
      </a>
    </li> -->
  </ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I created a var in every `.sub-menu`

the first have `--detail: 1;` the last `--delay: 7;`

now using `calc();` in css, we can make a small delay in the first, more we go more the delay

```css
.menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.submenu {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animate 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * 0.5s);
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(5);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 1;">1</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 2;">2</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 3;">3</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 4;">4</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 5;">5</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 6;">6</div>
    <div class="submenu" style="--delay: 7;">7</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```